# Expected a string, got object gatsby-plugin-prettier-eslint Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, prettier, gatsby-plugin, prettier-eslint

I am trying to learn Gatsby and I included prettier-eslint plugin with a common configuration. You can see my configuration, the files, etc

When I try to add a css file I get this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: I ran into this problem when updating Prettier to v3.0.0. Downgrading it fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the following?

```
eslint: {
  patterns: "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  customOptions: {
    fix: true,
    cache: true,
  },
},
```

The `eslint` pattern seems to be a string, not an array according to the [plugin's example](https://github.com/andreabreu-me/gatsby-plugin-prettier-eslint).

---

This seems to be an unresolved issue of the plugin, according to this [opened issue](https://github.com/andreabreu-me/gatsby-plugin-prettier-eslint/issues/10) (from a week ago), so keep an eye on that stack trace to see how it evolves. If the dependency has a bug when using the defaults (and suggested) configuration, there's nothing you can do except making a PR if you are able to spot the bug in the source code or wait for the resolution.

Comment: Yes, that was my first configuration, and thanks for sharing the issue I will follow it. I'm currently trying to use Vscode extension

Comment: I'm also using prettier and ESLint in all my projects and I don't use any Gatsby's plugin. You can use the default's configuration for prettier (the `.prettierrc` file) and the `eslintrc.js` placed at the root of the project. Give it a try, you may not need to use the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out you **must** have a prettier config (.prettierrc or similar) set up. Check to make sure you have a config as mentioned [in the Prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).